# sorting List<string[]> by many columns

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have List which I would like to sort by many columns. For example, string[] has 5 elements (5 columns) and List has 10 elements (10 rows). For example I would like to start sorting by 1st column, then by 3rd and then by 4th.

How could it be done in the easiest way with C#?

I thought about such algorithm:

1. Delete values corresponding to those columns that I don't want to use for sorting
2. Find for each of columns that are left, the longest string that can be used to store their value
3. Change each row to string, where each cell occupies as many characters as there is maximum number of characters for the value for the given column
4. Assign int with index for each of those string values
5. Sort these string values
6. Sort the real data, with help of already sorted indices

But I think this algorithm is very bad. Could you suggest me any better way, if possible, that uses already existing features of C# and .NET?

Comment: Just call `OrderBy()` with a delegate that looks up the comparand.

Answer (score 5):

```
List<string[]> list = .....

var newList = list.OrderBy(x => x[1]).ThenBy(x => x[3]).ThenBy(x => x[4]).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! That's almost exactly what I was looking for. However, I use string[] because first time when I know about number of columns is during execution. In your solution it is limited to three columns and it should be a little bit more flexible (with i columns rather than 3 columns). Is there any way to achieve it with this method? Regards!

Comment: First use `var query = list.OrderBy(x => x[i]);`, then at runtime you can add many times `query = query.ThenBy(x => x[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var rows = new List<string[]>();

var sortColumnIndex = 2;

rows.Sort((a, b) => return a[sortColumnIndex].CompareTo(b[sortColumnIndex]));
```

This will perform an in-place sort -- that is, it will sort the contents of the list.

Sorting on multiple columns is possible, but requires more logic in your comparer delegate.

If you're happy to create another collection, you can use the Linq approach given in another answer.

---

**EDIT** here's the multi-column, in-place sorting example:

```
var rows = new List<string[]>();

var sortColumnIndices = new[] { 1, 3, 4 };

rows.Sort((a, b) => {
    for (var index in sortColumnIndices)
    {
        var result = a[index].CompareTo(b[index]);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: When you do the second sort ,as asked in the question, you will loose the order in the first sort.

Comment: @I4V, not if you do it properly in the comparer. You would only call `Sort` once, and the comparer would loop through columns to be ordered by, returning the result of the first comparison that does not return zero..